# How to find all possible solution in the problem of simplex mesthod in maple?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

I have an object to maximize and some constraints in Maple, but Maple just give me only one solution. How can I get more than one solution, i.e. I would like to know all possible solution for the variables. Is there any command that can be used in Maple?

Comment: This site isn't the right site to ask about how to do things in Maple.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume all your coefficients are rational numbers.

First find the optimum value of the objective function using the exact simplex method, then add the constraint "objective function = optimum value" to your constraint set.  Now you have to enumerate the vertices of the resulting polytope, which you can do using the [Convex](http://www.math.uwo.ca/~mfranz/convex/) package.  That will give you every vertex that is a solution.  The convex hull of those is the set of all solutions.

But I never did it, so someone can tell us this won't work...